# Instantaneous DC output using Laplace transform

Tags: dc, laplace-transform

I am testing a feedback system in which a feedback signal from sensor is applied to a correction network and then compared with threshold values.

I need some clue on how to get around this task, I will be applying DC voltage to the network and will compare its output obtained with the one I calculated theoretically. Here is the transfer function of the network with a natural frequency of 90Hz

$$H(s)=\dfrac{1+0.145s+0.0019s^2}{1+\dfrac{0.8}{150 }s+\dfrac{1}{150²}s²}×\dfrac{1}{1+0.0012s}×\dfrac{1}{1+0.008s}$$

I calculated the output of the network by finding its inverse Laplace with step function as its input. The issue is that the output voltage obtained from solving this is a non-linear function hence changes it at every instant so how am I supposed to test the output for a particular DC input?

Any ideas?

Here is the step response I plotted using Matlab

[image]

Comment: Why is it non-linear?

Comment: @Andyaka there are exponential terms in v(t) equation

Comment: @Chu Exactly voltage will vary with time but my problem is i do not understand at which time stamp to pick output voltage to test the circuit? so that I can compare the calculated result with the observed one.

Comment: @alexhilton, taking (4 x time constant) as the transient decay time, the decay times for the various terms are approximately: 4.8ms, 32ms, and 67ms. To be on the safe side you may want to give it 0.1s. (67ms is for the 2nd order TF, using 4/(zeta x wn))

Comment: @Chu According to system specs damping for a second order damped system is defined as 1.5 are you using damping factor to find settling time? and do you mean that I should consider the output at t tends to infinity? Wont that give  step input magnitude at output? Please elaborate

Comment: @alexhilton, I have to do an answer because comment is too long

Answer (score 1):

What you have are: two 1st order lag terms, and a 2nd order underdamped term with the slight complication of a 2nd order numerator.

The general ROT is that the settling time for a 1st order lag is \$4\tau\$ where \$\tau\$ is the time constant (\$\tau\$ is the coefficient of \$s\$ in the general term: \$1/(1+\tau s)\$). The settling time for a 2nd order denominator term is given by: \$4/(\zeta \times \omega_n)\$ where \$\zeta\$ is the damping coefficient and \$\omega_n\$ is the natural frequency.

One standard form for the 2nd order denominator is: \$1 + 2(\zeta/\omega_n)s + s^2/\omega_n^2\$

In your case \$\omega_n=150\$ rad/sec and \$\zeta=0.4\$, hence the settling time for this term is \$4/(0.4 \times 150) = 0.067 = 67\$ms. Note, for this particular application we can ignore the 2nd order numerator as it only has a small effect on the transient generated by the denominator.

The two 1st order terms give settling times: \$4 \times 1.2 = 4.8\$ms, and \$4 \times 8 = 32\$ms. The longest settling time is thus \$67\$ms, after which all the transients may be considered spent.

The steady-state gain (or 'DC gain') of the sensor is unity. This can determined by setting \$s = 0\$ in the TF.

Here's a useful plotting tool for time domain and frequency domain responses from Laplace TFs:

http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/dtool.php

Comment: Please take some time to learn how to format math nicely on this site. It will greatly improve the readability and quality of your answers. There's an extensive tutorial on [Math.SE meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and a more specific tutorial for EE.SE on [EE.SE meta](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/434/test-the-new-latex-markdown-in-this-sandbox-question).

Comment: @Null, You're quite right, I've been lazy with this.

Comment: There's a bit of a learning curve, but once you start using MathJax you'll pick it up in pieces and get better and better at it. Also, if you're curious how a particular post formats something, you can click the "edit" button just to look at the post's source. You can pick it up even faster that way.

Comment: @Chu Thanks for the detailed explanation. I will now calculate output at 70-100ms. Will you please check the link below I calculated the results here, should I calculate the output using the last equation where t is assumed to be real?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+Laplace+transform+%281%2B0.145s%2B0.0019s%5E2%29%2F%281%2B0.8%2F150+s%2B%281%2F150%29%C2%B2s%C2%B2%29%C3%971%2F%281%2B0.0012s%29%C3%971%2F%281%2B0.008s%29

Comment: @alexhilton, the Wolfram answer 'assuming t is real' is the one to go for if you need to use the values in another application

Comment: @Chu I simulated the function in Matlab and calculated its step response, please check the curve, is the settling time t=79ms correct? I have edited my question with the curve I plotted

Comment: @alexhilton, it looks like an impulse response. Also, you could edit the question to remove the reference to non-linear - the system is linear.

Comment: @Chu this is a step response, I used simple matlab step command to plot this